# Rails 5.2 Active Storage direct upload failure: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: amazon-s3, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am trying out Rail 5.2.0.rc1 Active Storage, using its included JavaScript library to upload PDF docs directly from the client to the cloud.
But on submitting a form I get a browser error in both Firefox & Chrome:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked... (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Headers are set thus this.xhr.setRequestHeader... in the activestorage.js and dont appear to be configurable: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/javascript/activestorage/blob_record.js

any suggestions anyone?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try setting the CORS permission on the S3 bucket with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that solves it. Next issue though is 403 forbidden is returned, which of course goes away if I grant full public access on the S3 bucket. But hopefully we dont have to do that?

Comment: Are you sure the URL isn't expired?

Comment: If only that were the case!
No, this appears to be about granting the right permissions on the bucket in AWS.
To investigate have saved a bucket policy granting full access to the account ( "Action": "s3:*" ), then logged in as that account. But as that user I get access denied when trying to download a file I just uploaded!

Comment: All of the steps we took to get direct upload working are here: https://keithpblog.org/post/active-storage-on-amazon-s3/

Comment: Answer still works on Rails 5.2.4 while developing locally on my machine (localhost:3000).

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the new S3 console, the CORS configuration must be JSON. the following is working correctly:

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "POST",
            "GET",
            "PUT"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```